# Encriptar o Desencriptar PasswordHash Asp.Net Identity Core con C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, identity

Estoy tratando de desacoplar un proyecto que tiene Asp.net Identity Core en N Capas, pero no me ha sido posible hacerlo. Lo que quiero hacer ahora es Encriptar o Desencriptar la contraseña ya que si logro hacer ésto podría seguir con mi proyecto de ante mano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

me explico, en mi API al consumir un método mando como clave 123456, que al  encriptarla la pueda comparar contra la base de datos como se encuentra en la tabla [dbo].[AspNetUsers].

[image: Imagen de la tabla AspNetUsers]

Gracias por la pronta respuesta.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente es una muy mala idea utilizar encriptación bidireccional de passwords. La razón es simple, desencriptar una clave, una vez que se conoce cuál es el algoritmo de cifrado/descifrado, es simplemente una cuestión de tiempo. Mucho tiempo para algunos algoritmos, sobre todo de clave pública/privada, y poco para otros en los que se pueden aplicar reducciones de espacio de claves teniendo en cuenta que las haya introducido un usuario normal.

Actualmente es posible utilizar fuerza bruta con mucha eficiencia utilizando tarjetas gráficas y clusters de ordenadores con aceleradores gráficos o DSPs.

La opción más segura en no almacenar la clave, sino un `hash` unidireccional que utilice un algoritmo que permita vectores de inicialización aleatorios, `salt`.

Hay una serie de artículos de [Andrew Lock](https://andrewlock.net) [[aquí hay uno](https://andrewlock.net/safely-migrating-passwords-in-asp-net-core-identity-with-a-custom-passwordhasher/)] que te serán muy útiles para tratar este tema. No te reproduzco aquí el contenido ni la explicación porque en ellos está mucho mejor explicado de lo que podría yo ponerte aquí.